# Saving Data in Firebase Realtime Database with Unique Key + custom name

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if there is a problem with saving Data like this.

[Json-tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrPA5.png)

As you can see I have used a unique ID but wrote the title infront of it to make it easier to identify what I'm looking at as a human.

the reference looks like this:

```
let storyLocation = Database.database().reference().child("storyDetails").child("\(titel)(\(storyID!))")
```

It works all fine at this point but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, when the project gets bigger.

Right now I see 3 potential problems.

1. This might require a bit more storage
2. It could slow down writing and retrieving from the Database
3. If we assume that a Title could later be changed, it has to be changed in different places at the same time.

I'm still quite new to this Topic. So I would like to know if someone with more experience would save data like this or if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally save JUST the id as the key instead of title and storyId combined. I also wouldn't save the id inside of that as you can simply get a hold of the id by accessing the key like so `let id = snapshot.key`. Simply store the author and title inside it to be more efficient.

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer. I will do it that way :)

Comment: @130 It's a little confusing at first but if you already have the data stored, it's not efficient to add it again. I hope this makes sense. If this has helped you in any way shape or form, I'd appreciate an upvote! :) Just let me know if the likes of snapshot.key makes any sense or not

Comment: snapshot.key helped me a lot i didnt knew that was possible haha
I need 5 more reputations so that my upvotes can count. But then you will get it :)